# Server product delivery model with Android in-app purchases?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Say the app sells songs and the actual songs are stored on an outside server.

The app sends a download request for a song. The server now needs to authenticate that the user has actually bought the song before sending the MP3 file.

Apple provides a simple API through which the server can verify the request. [See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH104-SW1).

Browsing through Android developer documentation I didn't find anything on the subject, so how does one solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is handled almost the same way. Your app can request a signed receipt which your server can verify with the public key that you can find in your Android Market publishers account profile: https://market.android.com/publish/editProfile

You can find the official documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/index.html